# Call UIView method from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I created a two separate xib files for a line graph and a bar chart and linked it to a view in my scene. I assigned the nib depending on the type of data. I have a function `setChart()` in my UIView class which I need to call from my ViewController to draw the charts.

How do I call the function `setChart()` from my ViewController? My code doesn't work

UIView:

```
class BarChartDashboard: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    .....
}

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    .....
}


}
```

ViewController:

```
class DetailDashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var chartView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    runQueries(2)

    if index != 3{
        chartView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BarChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }
    else{
        chartView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LineChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    }
}
}

private extension DetailDashboardViewController {

func runQueries(period: Int) {

    self.query(false, periodIndex: period){ (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            // do second task if success
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if self.index != 3{
                    (self.chartView as! BarChartDashboard).setChart(self.yAxis, values: self.xAxis)
                }
                else{
                    (self.chartView as! LineChartDashboard).setChartData(self.yAxis, yAxisMax: self.xAxisMax, yAxisMin : self.xAxisMin)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}


func query(min: Bool, periodIndex: Int, completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    .......
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new variable `chart` in your ViewController and add this chart as `subView` to the `view` `outlet` connected from xib

Your ViewController class would look like below:

```
class DetailDashboardViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var chartView: UIView!
var chart: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        if index != 3{
            chart = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BarChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? BarChartDashboard
     }
        else{
            chart = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LineChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? LineChartDashboard
        }

    self.chartView.addSubView(chart)
    self.chart.frame = self.chartView.bounds
    runQueries(2)
    }

private extension DetailDashboardViewController {

func runQueries(period: Int) {

    self.query(false, periodIndex: period){ (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            // do second task if success
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                if self.index != 3{
                    (self.chart as! BarChartDashboard).setChart(self.yAxis, values: self.xAxis)
                }
                else{
                    (self.chart as! LineChartDashboard).setChartData(self.yAxis, yAxisMax: self.xAxisMax, yAxisMin : self.xAxisMin)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `DetailDashboardViewController` you have made an instance of your view as type of `UIView` while your custom `UIView` class is named `BarChartDashboard`, so in order to be able to call method `setChart()` you should set the class of your view in class inspector to `BarChartDashboard` as well as in your `DetailDashboardViewController` instance variable should be changed as follow:

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: BarChartDashboard!
```

So now the instance variable is type of `BarChartDashboard` and now method `setChart()` can be called from your `DetailDashboardViewController`.

In your `DetailDashboardViewController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: BarChartDashboard!
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     runQueries(2)

     if index != 3{
        chartView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("BarChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
     }
     else{
        chartView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LineChartDashboard", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
     }
     chartView.setChart(dataPoints: ["hello","world"], values: [20.0,21.5])
}
```